# How to change motor oil on a Chevy Cruze 2017

Tags: chevrolet, oil-change, cruze

I have a 2017 Chevy Cruze 1.5L I believe. Is there anything specific that needs to be reset on the digital odometer, and where is the oil drain plug and filter?

Comment: I only see a 1.4 turbo (gas) or 1.6 turbo (diesel) engine listed ... are you sure you have the right size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1.4L Turbo ECOTEC engine on a 2017 Chevy Cruze, there are two different ways to reset the oil life indicator. It depends on whether you have the steering wheel controls or not.

For steering wheel controls, do the following:

[image]

- Press the left/right arrows until you get to the car icon on the display

[image]

- Press the down arrow until you get to **Remaining Oil Life**

[image]

- Press and hold the check mark (in the center of the pad)
- The system will ask Yes/No if you want to reset, press the up/down arrows once to highlight **Yes**, then press the check mark

If you don't have the steering wheel controls, you'll need to use the turn signal stalk (on the left of the steering column), which should look like this:

[image]

- Press the **Menu** button
- Rotate the arrowed ring up/down to locate the **Remaining Oil Life**
- Press and hold the button on the end of the turn signal stalk
- The system will ask Yes/No if you want to reset, rotate the up/down arrows once to highlight **Yes**, then press the check button again

To change the oil, the filter and drain plug are on the bottom of the car.  Locate the drain plug in the center rear of the oil pan. It should be a 15mm bolt head with a silver tone on a black oil pan (hard to miss). The oil filter is towards the front of the oil pan. You'll need 4.5 quarts of 5w-30 Full Synthetic as replacement.